# Alternative WMS servers for GOES-East satellite imagery

Tags: weather-satellites

I'm having some difficulty finding a WMS (web mapping server) for North America GOES-East satellite imagery that matches my needs (visible and IR4, timely, with no alteration of grey-scale pixel values).

I have tried the Iowa State and Nowcoast servers, but, for various reasons, the data isn't exactly what I need. I would like to experiment with other WMS servers, but I can't find any.

Do you know of any alternative WMS servers for GOES-East satellite imagery, other than Iowa State and Nowcoast?

Answer (score 1):

The Real Earth server from SSEC seems to be a good choice.

https://realearth.ssec.wisc.edu/doc/dataaccess.php